# ORA-21700 on SELECT FROM package-user-defined TABLE

Tags: plsql, package, user-defined-types

I'm creating an Oracle package (`MyPackage`) where I have a public custom type table (`ObjDataCollection`) of custom type records (`ObjData`), which will be used as IN parameter for one of the Package functions (`Calculate`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MyPackage AS
    TYPE ObjData IS RECORD (
        t date NOT NULL := DATE '0001-01-01',
        v number(9, 4)
    );
    TYPE ObjDataCollection IS TABLE
        OF ObjData;
    FUNCTION Calculate(
        DataSource IN ObjDataCollection
    ) RETURN number;
END MyPackage;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MyPackage AS
    FUNCTION Calculate(
        DataSource IN ObjDataCollection
    ) RETURN number IS
        res number(9, 4) := 0;
        dateStart date;
        dsv ObjData;
        CURSOR q1 (dt date) IS
            SELECT * FROM TABLE(DataSource) --Throws ORA-21700: Object does not exist or is marked for delete oracle.
            WHERE t >= dt
            ORDER BY t;
    BEGIN
        -- some irrelevant code
        dateStart := DATE '2015-01-01';
        OPEN q1(dateStart);
        LOOP FETCH q1 INTO dsv;
            EXIT WHEN q1%NOTFOUND;
            res := res + dsv.v;
            -- some irrelevant code
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE q1;
        -- some irrelevant code
        return res;
    END Calculate;
END MyPackage;
```

I debbuged my code and I get the error on the second line of the cursor (marked in code):

> ORA-21700: Object does not exist or is marked for delete oracle.

I'm using this data to execute my package:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (d date DEFAULT DATE '0001-01-01', v number(9, 4));
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (DATE '2015-01-01', 2.1);
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (DATE '2015-01-08', 3.1);
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (DATE '2015-01-15', 4.1);
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (DATE '2015-01-22', 5.1);
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (DATE '2015-01-29', 6.1);
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (DATE '2015-02-05', 7.1);
```

And this code to run a test:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TestMyPackage AS
    res MyPackage.ObjDataCollection;
    counter number(9, 4);
BEGIN
    SELECT d, v
        BULK COLLECT INTO res
        FROM TestTable
        ORDER BY v;
    counter := MyPackage.Calculate(res);
END TestMyPackage;
```

Why I recieve this ORA-21700 exception?

Comment: While package compilations you should get other error(PLS-00642). Because isn't possible to use local collection type in select statement.
Create schema level object  and use them in your package. 
create type ObjData as object (   t date , v number(9, 4))
create type ObjDataCollection as TABLE        OF ObjData;

Comment: I need to distribute it as a independent Package, that's why I have input data model, instead of reading directly from database.

Comment: Don't use cursor in calculate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
PACKAGE BODY MyPackage AS
    FUNCTION Calculate(
        DataSource IN ObjDataCollection
    ) RETURN number IS
        res BINARY_FLoAT:= 0;
        dateStart date;
        dsv ObjData;
        copy_of_DataSource ObjDataCollection;

        procedure sortCollection(toSort in out ObjDataCollection)
        is
          type idx_coll  is table of ObjData;
          type sort_help is table of idx_coll index by varchar2(16 char);
           v_sort sort_help;
           v_temp varchar2(16);
           v_result ObjDataCollection := new ObjDataCollection();
           v_cnt PLS_INTEGER := 0;
        begin
          for i in nvl(toSort.first,1) .. nvl(toSort.last,-1) loop
              v_temp := to_char(toSort(i).t,'yyyymmddhh24miss');
              if v_sort.exists(v_temp) then
                 v_sort(v_temp).extend(1);
                 v_sort(v_temp)(v_sort(v_temp).count) := toSort(i);
              else
                 v_sort(v_temp) := idx_coll(toSort(i));
              end if;
          end loop;
          v_result.extend(toSort.count);
          v_temp := v_sort.first;
          while v_temp is not null loop
              for i in nvl(v_sort(v_temp).first,1) .. nvl(v_sort(v_temp).last,-1) loop
                 v_cnt := v_cnt +1;
                 v_result(v_cnt) := v_sort(v_temp)(i);
              end loop;
              v_temp := v_sort.next(v_temp);
          end loop;
          toSort := v_result;
        end;

    BEGIN
        -- some irrelevant code
        copy_of_DataSource := DataSource;
        dateStart := DATE '2015-01-01';
        sortCollection(copy_of_DataSource);
        for i in nvl(copy_of_DataSource.first,1) .. nvl(copy_of_DataSource.last,-1) loop
          if copy_of_DataSource(i).t > dateStart then
             res := res +  copy_of_DataSource(i).v;
             dbms_output.put_line(copy_of_DataSource(i).t);
          end if;
        end loop;
        -- some irrelevant code
        return res;
    END Calculate;
END MyPackage;
```

Comment: I already though in this option, but data sorting is a requirement too.

Comment: But you have fetched data in to collection in right order.

Comment: Yes I did, but as is a package, customers want data and business logic layers independent one of other

Comment: Sort collection using table indexed by.

Comment: Can't add an index of a user-type table inside a package.

Answer (score 0):

As it was a task due to a date, I ended up fixing it by creating user-defined types and tables at schema level as suggested [Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5019309/arkadiusz-%C5%81ukasiewicz) in one of his comments. Thank you for your effort.

As is not what I wanted, I won't mark any answer as Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem and solved it by doing the following steps:

1. Drop package where type is defined
2. Drop package using that type
3. Compile package with type
4. Compile target package

I got this ORA-21700 after adding new constants in a package with types/constants. I guess there's some internal issue with dependencies but I haven't dug a lot.